How can I select select just the first parent element which contains another element with a given class within it?
I'm looking for a way to select the first, and only the first, parent element which contains another element with a given class within it.
So for example:
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner-element type-a">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <!-- want to select this one -->
    <div class="inner-element type-b">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner-element type-b">
      <!-- but not this one -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

So I can use .wrapper .item:has(.inner-element.type-b) to select all of the item divs which contain an element with the type-b class but I only want to target the first one.
I tried .wrapper .item:has(.inner-element.type-b):first-of-type but that didn't seem to target the element correctly. Is this even possible with CSS alone or is my combination of selectors the issue?

Please take the time to format your code properly. No one likes working with walls of text.

You can use:


.item:nth-child(1 of :has(.inner-element.type-b)) {
  border:1px solid red;
}


[class]:before {
  content:attr(class);
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner-element type-a">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <!-- want to select this one -->
    <div class="inner-element type-b">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner-element type-b">
      <!-- but not this one -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Some explanation of your techniques (or reference links) would be most appreciated. I've never used of in 25 years of web development, and I'm not sure what your second rule does at a glance.

of is an additional param we can pass via :nth-child to only select elements which match a given criteria and the second part of his code merely displays the class of each element before it to make them easier to identify visually.

A possible option is to apply your first rule then "unapply" it to subsequent elements you don't  wish to style with the adjacent sibling selector ~ e.g.
.wrapper .item:has(.inner-element.type-b) {
  border: 1px solid red
}

.wrapper .item:has(.inner-element.type-b) ~ .item:has(.inner-element.type-b) {
  border: unset
}


This is a perfectly valid and appreciated approach too, the only reason I selected @temani-afif's response over it was that it seems more elegant to only target the element required.
